# Quadratic approximation of vector valued functions

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, hessian-matrix

What is the best second order approximation using Taylor's theorem for vector value functions? Specifically in the case when $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ and then $g= \nabla f$ then the first order approximation by Taylor's theorem is 
$
g(x) = g(a)+(x-a) \cdot \nabla g(a) + ... = g(a) + (x-a) \cdot H(f)(a)+...
$ what would be the third term in this approximation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables

Comment: @amd those are scalar valued functions...

Comment: Apply individually to each component.

Comment: @amd So the Hessian of a Hessian is going to be what, a matrix with matrices as entries?

Comment: More or less. All of those higher-order derivatives are tensors.